# How to update the order of elements in an array using N1QL in a couchbase document

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have a couchbase doc which contains an array (along with several other keys). Is it possible to update the order of elements in this array using N1QL query.

for example

```
{
    networkList: [
       {'name': 'network1'},
       {'name': 'network2'},
       {'name': 'network3'}
  ]
}
```

becomes

```
{
    networkList: [
       {'name': 'network2'},
       {'name': 'network1'},
       {'name': 'network3'}
  ]
}
```

NOTE: I do not want to sort the list. I just want to change the position of any given element. for example moving the second element to first position in the above example.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Checkout the array functions https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/arrayfun.html
ARRAY_INSERT(ARRAY_REMOVE(networkList, {'name': 'network2'}),0,{'name': 'network2'})

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
The use case is that I need to move a particular element(lets say 3rd element) to a particular position(lets say 1st) for a number of docs. The element is an object and may have different key value pairs for different docs so hardcoding values in query won't work.

I'll try using this with array indexes. let's see if it works.

Comment: ARRAY_INSERT(ARRAY_REMOVE(networkList, networkList[3]),0,networkList[3]))

Comment: @vsr thanks, a ton man. Got this working. Can you please post it as an answer, might help others who got similar use-case and lands on this page in search of an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REMOVE the ARRAY element from given position and insert into desired position like below.
ARRAY_INSERT(ARRAY_REMOVE(networkList, networkList[3]),0,networkList[3]))